# How to make cron run only 42 times in 10 minute intervals?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I need to make a job run 42 times in intervals of 10 minutes. I will be doing this using AWS Scheduled Task, which has the following cron syntax: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html

The basic arithmetic formula I came up with:

```
42 * 10 minutes = 420 minutes / 60 minutes = 7 hours.
```

That means I want the Scheduled Task to run in intervals of 10 minutes over 7 hours. Once it reaches that 7 hours, it just no longer runs for the rest of the day.

Given this, I came up with this expression?

```
cron(1/10,15-21,*,*,?,*)
```

Is this expression accurate and most efficient for my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the expression should actually be `cron(1/10 15-21 * * ? *)` so you would want to remove the commas between.

You have offset the minute part of the expression by `1` so it will run at 1,11,21,31,41,51. If you simply wanted it to run once every 10 minutes then you could do `*/10` instead.

This will run 6 times in an hour 7 hours so that checks out as your count of 42 which is what you expect ranging from `15:01` to `21:51`.

Just be aware that this is executed in `UTC` so ensure that the times match any time zone that you're expecting it to operate it.